# No such file or directory when using csv to write to a database

Tags: python, pandas

I am experimenting with bulk upload of a `dataframe` into a database table. I have following code that first writes the `dataframe` into a `csv` and then copies the content of the `csv` into the database table. The error I am getting is `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not open file "C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\etc\demand_override.csv" for reading: No such file or directory` However when I copy and paste above directory into explorer, the csv file opens! Where am I doing it wrong?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
engine = create_engine("postgresql://myapp:mypass@project.com/my_database")
schema = 'scenario_1'

df = pd.read_csv('./input/demand_override.csv')

t2 = time.time()
cwd = os.getcwd()
df.to_csv(cwd+'/'+'demand_override.csv', index=False)
copy_query = "COPY " + schema + "." + 'demand_override' + " FROM '"  + cwd + '\\' + 'demand_override.csv' + "' CSV HEADER"
_connection = engine.connect()
_connection.execute(copy_query)
```